# Multiple Permissions Dialogs in Android using Sign in with Google after orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, google-signin, android-configchanges

I've been wrestling with this one for a while -- and I've searched extensively for answers on here but haven't found any (so apologies if I've missed a resolution). I'm implementing a "Sign in with Google" button/logic and all works fine EXCEPT when it comes to changing device orientation. In that case, I am presented with multiple copies of Google's permissions dialog. (So if I change orientation three times, there are then three copies of the permissions dialog I have to cancel out of before being returned back to my original screen). (An example of the permissions dialog can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/images/native-permissions.png)).

I thought I had over-complicated the code so I made a new activity with nothing but the code from Google's tutorial pages ([Getting Started/Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)), and I am still having the same issue. (Code below)

(FWIW, I also tried creating a new Activity using IntelliJ's "New --> Activity --> Login Activity" option, with the same results.)

In addition to that, I tried running Google's "Quickstart" app and yes, the same issue is still happening!

Has anyone else successfully implemented "Sign in with Google" WITHOUT this behavior? I suppose as a last resort I could force my authentication activity to always appear in portrait, but I'm trying to see if there's a resolution beyond that.

Thank you in advance!

Following is my code from my "simplified" Activity:

```
package com.myapp.test.view.housekeeping;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.myapp.test.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class AuthenticateActivity_BareBones extends ActionBarActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    /* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
     * all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
     */
    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    /* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
     * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
     */
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticate);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    mSignInClicked = false;
                }

                mIntentInProgress = false;

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.login_authenticate_google_button:
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mSignInClicked = true;
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.  mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to Google!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    /* A helper method to resolve the current ConnectionResult error. */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue still exists in the new Google Play Services lib 7.0.1 (and you reproduce it easily with the samples app). Additionally to what you have written, the issue happens also on the account chooser dialog.
@QuantumSheep Have find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The mSignInClicked is actually guarding the rotation case for you in this code, so the resolution is being fired properly, just once. I get the same behaviour with the Account Chooser dialog being redisplayed multiple times.

This looks like a bug in version 7 of Google Play Services - will file this upstream, and hopefully it should be taken care of in a future version.